# Using Select by Attributes for large list of values in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, sql, pandas

I have a CSV of integers containing meter numbers varying from 9 digits to 11 digits. I've written a simple script to read CSV to a list.

```
import pandas as pd
path = "example_path.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path)
meter_list = df['MeterNumber'].to_list()
```

From here I want to select all features that have a meter number within `meter_list`. The issue is the field in my feature class's data type is text. I've converted `meter_list` to have string values but the issue is there are inconsistent character lengths in my feature class. For example,
('123456789', '123456789   ', '1234567890'). I've tried using wildcard searches in SQL but none have worked so far.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Comment: I dont understand. `1234` in csv you want to select all features starting with `1234`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the IN() query.  There are several options for building an IN() query using a list in python.  Probably all of these were taken from this Stack Exchange over the years

```py
id_list = df['MeterNumber'].to_list()

#This option is easiest to read, but requires than the list have at least 2 entries.
#And I think it also requires the list / target field to be the same type (numeric/text)
where_clause = '"IDfield" IN ' + str(tuple(id_list))

#This approach works even if the list only has one entry.
#Use different quotes if the field you are selecting on is text vs numeric
where_clause = "NumberField IN ({:s})".format(','.join(f"{x}" for x in id_list))
where_clause = "TextField IN ({:s})".format(','.join(f"'{x}'" for x in id_list))

#Then just select by attribute
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(tbl, 'NEW_SELECTION', where_clause)
```

Comment: The second approach worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: One follow-up question. What would the Python 2.7 alternative be for the `where_clause`?

Comment: @cb101, the Python version does not impact SQL syntax, and ArcGIS Desktop/ArcMap has a `where_clause` parameter just like Pro.

Comment: @bixb0012 I'm aware of that but in the Text Field `where_clause` it uses an f-string in the join which doesn't work in 2.7. When I remove the f-string it just repeats {x}.

Comment: @cb101, Replace `"f{x}"` with `"{}".format(x)`